# Array of methods in swift without reference cycle

Tags: arrays, swift, function-pointers, swift4.2

My goal is to create a class which contains an array. The elements of the array will be the methods of the same class. like:

```
class MyClass {
    lazy var functions = [self.myFirstMethod, self.mySecondMethod]

    deinit {
        print("Deinit")
    }

    func myFirstMethod() {
        // Do Something
    }

    func mySecondMethod() {
        // Do Something
    }

    func executeAll() {
        for f in functions {
            f()
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the `executeAll()` it works fine and I achieve my expected result:

```
var myObject = MyClass()
myObject.executeAll()
```

The problem is, it create reference cycle. Instance of `MyClass` holds the array `functions` and `functions` array holds `self`. So If I write below code:

```
var myObject: MyClass? = MyClass()
myObject.executeAll()
myObject = nil
```

It will not call `deinit` method because of this strong reference cycle.
How can I add method pointers to array as `weak self`? I don't want to use a local copy of functions in `executeAll` method.

Comment: why not just declare your `functions` variable as optional, and simply set it to nil after the execution since you want it to be deallocated after.

Answer (score 2):

If the method list is independent of the particular instance then you can make it a *type property* and avoid the reference cycle:

```
class MyClass {
    static let functions = [myFirstMethod, mySecondMethod]

    func executeAll() {
        for f in MyClass.functions {
            f(self)()
        }
    }

   // ...
}
```

The array elements are “curried functions” of the type

```
(MyClass) -> () -> ()
```

compare [Instance Methods are “Curried” Functions in Swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).

Answer (score -1):

Try this way,

```
class Unowned<T: AnyObject> {
    unowned let value: T
    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

var myObject: MyClass = MyClass()
var myUnowned = Unowned(myObject)
myUnowned.value.executeAll()
```

Comment: I am afraid that this would not solve the retain cycle problem. If you set `myObject = nil` *after*  calling `myUnowned.value.executeAll()` the the object is not deallocated. And if you set `myObject = nil` *before*  calling `myUnowned.value.executeAll()` then you'll get a crash.

Comment: Are you doing that on playground ?

Comment: No, in a compiled project. A Playground is not good for testing object (de)allocation.

Comment: i know, was making sure you're not

Comment: Try `let myUnowned = Unowned(MyClass()); myUnowned.value.executeAll()` ... 