# How to pass functions from class instance into array in Swift

Tags: swift

Not sure if this is the best approach but I want to have functions accessible by an index and would prefer not to use a dictionary. So I was thinking of putting them into an array.

```
var array = [ func1, func2, ... ]
```

It looks like this is possible since functions are first class citizens.

- [Passing functions as parameters in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717313/passing-functions-as-parameters-in-swift)
- https://www.aidanf.net/learn-swift/functions

BUt I'm wondering if you can do this on classes. That is, pass a function from a class instance to an array, without losing performance with extra closures.

```
class Foo {
  var array: [Function]

  init() {
    array = [ f1, f2 ]
  }

  func f1() {
    return array.length
  }

  func f2(a: Int, b: Int) {
    // ... the functions are all different.
  }
}
```

Wondering if anything like that is possible.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55038194/1187415.

Comment: Do all the functions have the same signature? Your first `func f1()` seems to return a value.

Comment: No sorry, they will all be different, I will update.

Comment: Then `f1` and `f2` have different types. You cannot store them in a common array (only as `Any` which makes things ugly).

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to know how to do it with Any anyway :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? With `var array: [Any]` you would have to cast each element back to the correct function type in order to call the function, i.e. you have to *know* the signature of every element (or try all possible signatures).

Comment: "That is, pass a function from a class instance to an array, without losing performance with extra closures." Nope. What you're trying to do, by definition, requires a closure, which captures the `self` parameter. You can capture an unbound instance method, but then you have to manually call it passing `self` to obtain a bound instance method.

Comment: @Alexander wondering if you can demo how to do that.

Comment: @LancePollard I don't have time right now, but check out my explanation on the bottom of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/348086/109689

Comment: When using function array, it’s much better to use same types of functions. Thus you can call foo.array[0](1,2) if change func f1 to func f1(_ I : int, _ f : Int){}. The array will have a fixed type not any!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift Arrays are homogeneous, but you can use `Any` to box any type at the expense of losing the type information, so yes you can stick all of your functions into a single array even though they have different types.  I don't particularly think its a good idea, but it does in fact work:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class Foo {
    var array: [Any] = []

    init() {
        array = [ f1, f2 ]
    }

    func f1() -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func f2(a: Int, b: Int) {
        // ... the functions are all different.
    }
}
```

maybe this is slightly less horrible if you use the Objective C run time, since its dynamic and you can use actually use [perform](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415652-performselector?language=objc) selector with arguments to invoke the selectors, but I still don't recommend it:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class Foo {
    var array: [Selector] = []

    init() {
        array = [#selector(f1), #selector(f2) ]
    }

    @objc func f1() -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    @objc func f2(a: Int, b: Int) {
        // ... the functions are all different.
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Option 3, enum with associated values (come up with more meaningful names than I have here):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class Foo {

    enum Function {
        case void_Int(() -> Int)
        case intInt_Void((Int,Int) -> Void)
    }

    var array: [Function] = []

    init() {
        array = [.void_Int(f1), .intInt_Void(f2) ]
    }

    @objc func f1() -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    @objc func f2(a: Int, b: Int) {
        // ... the functions are all different.
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely answers the question, but yeah I can see it not being ideal. I want to dynamically invoke a function given an integer, so an array was the first choice. Wondering what you would recommend instead. A switch statement would work, but that adds a _lot_ of processing given 100's of functions. A dictionary might work but that uses the hash under the hood. Maybe there are other approaches you know about.

Comment: If you truly don't need any type, but only finitely many types, use an enum with associated values for each possible type. This lets you put all of the functions into one array WITHOUT losing the string typing (ie the functions are boxed by the enum instead of by Any).

Comment: Maybe you wouldn't mind demoing that, I'm going to try [learning about enums](https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/). It sounds like you're saying an enum with the keys/value pairs being functions, and they will be indexed.